# WooCommerce: add/edit Vendor Categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on the Website, which was developed by another team.
The Website created with using WordPress, WooCommerce plugin and WooCommerce Product Vendors plugin.

The customer wants to add/change Vendor Categories (on create/edit Vendor Page).

How do I add/change Categories from these list of Vendor Categories?

[image: Vendor Categories]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vendor Categories are not part of the Vendor Plugin at all.
So it is probably Added via advanced custom fields or any other custom fields plugin.